# Does a subset with small cardinality represent the whole set?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, probability-distributions, it.information-theory, random-walks

Assume that we have heavy-tailed distribution $F(x)$ such that
\begin{align}
F(x)=\mathbb{P}[X\geq x]=x^{-0.5}.
\end{align}
Then, we produce $N$ independent samples $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$ from this distribution. Assuming that $n(N)\leq N$ is a function of $N$, we pick the $n(N)$ largest amounts among $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$ and produce the summation as
\begin{align}
S_{n(N)} = \sum_{\ell=1}^{n(N)} X_{i_\ell},
\end{align}
Here, $i_1, \ldots, i_{n(N)}$ represent the indices corresponding to the $n(N)$ largest values among the $N$ variables. The question is whether there exists a specific choice of $n(N)$ such that as $N$ approaches infinity, the ratio $n(N)/N$ tends to zero, and we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{S_{n(N)}}{S_{N}}= 1.
\end{align}
In other words, does a very small subset of variables represent the whole of them? How can I think about these kinds of problems to solve them?

Comment: $F(x)=\mathbb{P}[X\leq x]=x^{-0.5}$ is not here a typo?

Comment: If it should read as $X\geq x$, then we have a large number of order $n^2$ with high probability, thus the terms which are greater than $\sqrt{n} $ dominate the sum, and we have $o(n) $ such numbers

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I fixed it. I will be grateful if you write the answer in detail. I would like to know the details of such an analysis.

Comment: I would have written $F(x)= \Pr(X>x) = x^{-0.5} \text{ for } x\ge 1$ (being explicit about that lower bound). And also "a sample of $N$ independent observations from this distribution" rather than "$N$ samples from this distribution." $\qquad$

Comment: Does there exist a distribution that satisfies this?

Comment: Yes. $\alpha$-stable distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability that all samples are less than $N^{19/10}$ is $(1-N^{-19/20})^{N}$ that tends to 0. The expected number of samples greater than $N^{1/2}$ is $N^{3/4}$, thus, the probability that we have more than $N^{4/5}$ such samples is by Chebyshev inequality at most $N^{-1/20}$,also tends to 0. Therefore, with probability tending to 1 the sum of all but $N^{4/5}$ largest samples does not exceed $N^{3/2}$ while the sum of $N^{4/5}$ largest samples (and even one single largest sample) is at least $N^{19/10}$. It yields that you may take $n(N)=N^{4/5}$. Of course this is not optimal.

Comment: I think the $N^{19/20}$ towards the end is meant to be $N^{19/10}$.

Comment: @JamesMartin thank you, fixed

Comment: The expected number of samples less than $N^{1/2}$ is $NP(X<N^{1/2})\sim N$. Or, perhaps, I misunderstood what you meant by the expected number of samples less than $N^{1/2}$.

Comment: Also, I guess, instead of $N^{19/20}$, you meant $N^{-19/20}$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis thank you, fixed this too

Comment: Very nice! +1 ...

Comment: As I mentioned in comments under the question, I think you're using the word "sample" incorrectly. The whole sequence $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ is one sample, not $N$ samples. Otherwise, why would we speak of the size of a sample, or say that a bigger sample is needed, or speak of a "two-sample t-test"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis $\qquad\uparrow\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy you are probably correct. How should I call each $X_i$ instead?

Comment: @MichaelHardy : In [general parlance](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sample), "sample" may mean "specimen". In statistics, it usually means a sequence of sample points. I would be happy if terms like "sample" were totally banned on MO.  In this case, I would use "$X_i$'s" instead of "samples". However, I understood this answer and, because it is Fedor Petrov's, I had no doubts as to whether he understands what he is talking about. :-)